# Assist me with my JavaScript quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so I've been trying to make a randomized quiz with JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to make the answers portion. I have a randomly shuffled array containing both the questions and answers. I want to figure out how to make it so when the user enters the correct answer in the prompt, it will notify the user that they got it correct or incorrect.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "javascript">
var QandA = [
                { "Q":"2 + 2 = ?",  "A":"4"  },
                { "Q":"2 + 3 = ?",  "A":"5"  },
                { "Q":"5 + 5 = ?",  "A":"10" },
                { "Q":"3 + 3 = ?",  "A":"6"  },
                { "Q":"6 + 5 = ?",  "A":"11" },
                { "Q":"6 + 12 = ?", "A":"18" } 
            ];


var question = QandA[0].Q;  
var answer = QandA[0].A;    

var i = QandA.length, j, temp;
while(--i > 0){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1)); 
    temp = QandA[j];
    QandA[j] = QandA[i];
    QandA[i] = temp;
}
for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
var questions = prompt(QandA[i].Q);

}
document.write("<p>");
for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
console.log(QandA[i].A);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you have so far?

Comment: @Xotic750 can't figure out how to make the answers portion. I've made it so the questions and answers shuffle randomly, but I have no Idea how to make it so when the user enters the correct response to the prompt it gives them feedback. I'm sorry, I thought I made that clear above.

Comment: add an input field to your html, and a button. onclick the button should call a function that compares the input field to the answer.

Comment: Where in your code are you checking the users input against the expected result? That would be a good start.

Comment: @woodlumhoodlum Could you give me some help with that? I'm just beginning.

Comment: @Xotic750 I'm having a bit of trouble with that... :p

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? Do you know how to make conditionals with [`if..else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)?

Comment: Then you need a condition that `if answer equals expected then alert correct else alert incorrect`

Comment: @Xotic750 *Facepalm* Lol, I should've known that... thank you.

Comment: No problem, if you don't already know then [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a fantastic playground. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're prompting them for the answer and you're storing them into *questions*, so insert a condition to alert out a message based on whether they answered correctly.

A [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6U48z/1/) for testing purposes.

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    var questions = prompt(QandA[i].Q); // you're storing the user's answer in here
    if(questions == QandA[i].A) // check if their answer matches yours
        alert("Correct! Next question..."); // alert for correct
    else
        alert("Wrong... Next question..."); // alert for wrong
}
```

Of course, depending on where this code is going, you may want to switch out *alert* with printing feedback into an HTML element and *prompt* with a input field. In that case, you'd have a section or paragraph block for the quiz question and an input field for the answer.

Comment: No problem. :) However, depending on what your needs are for this quiz, you might want to look into creating a div to load the question in and accepting user input via a form input field. You could then check it and return a nice message in another div. If you're going to have a lot of questions, especially if they become complex and delve into comparing strings or searching strings (rather than comparing numbers for basic addition problems), you may want to move away from the pop-up approach. But, as the saying goes, whatever floats your boat.